# "Keyword not supported:'pdata source"

Tags: c#, connection-string

What does it mean by "Keyword not supported:'pdata source".As am struggling to find out what exactly is the problem?

```
        InitializeComponent();
        connString = "PData    Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\andrew\\Documents\\Vinyl0.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
        query = "SELECT * FROM Record";
        dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connString);
        dTable = new DataTable();
        cBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dAdapter);
        cBuilder.QuotePrefix = "[";
        cBuilder.QuoteSuffix = "]";
        myDataView = dTable.DefaultView;
        dAdapter.Fill(dTable);
        BindingSource bndSource = new BindingSource();
        bndSource.DataSource = dTable;
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = bndSource;
        for (int q = 0; q <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; q++)
        {
```

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string has a typo.  it should be

```
connString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\andrew\\Documents\\Vinyl0.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
              ^-----  not "PData    Source"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string is incorrect.

Change `PData    Source` to `Data Source` or `Server` and it should be fine.

See this [Building Connection Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms254947%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) article and also [this](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008) article to understand the construct of the connection strings based on your version/data adapter.

Comment: @DStanley updated, was more bothered about helping the OP understand connection string constructs :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `SqlDataAdapter` doesn't recognize the `PData` field.

And I don't recognize it either, have you tried getting rid of the part that says `PData`?